# Trac. Not all SVN revisions are displayed in the timeline

Tags: svn, trac

Some of the commits are not displayed in the timeline. What could be wrong?

Here's the timeline section of the config:

```
[timeline]
abbreviated_messages = True
changeset_collapse_events = false
changeset_long_messages = false
changeset_show_files = 0
default_daysback = 30
max_daysback = 90
newticket_formatter = oneliner
ticket_show_details = false
```

Comment: I go to the changeset, I see an audit, but there is no file list. Message (No files)

Comment: try to resync your Trac project via trac-admin